# How do implement a struct that takes a trait MyTrait<A>?

Tags: generics, rust, polymorphism, traits, parametric-polymorphism

I've defined a trait as follows:

```rust
trait Readable<E> {
    fn read_u8(&mut self) -> Result<u8, E>;
    fn read_u16be(&mut self) -> Result<u16, E>;
}
```

The idea is to implement it with different backends returning different error types. I tried to use it in a function:

```rust
fn f<E, R: Readable<E>>(r: &mut R) -> Result<u8, E> {
    r.read_u8()
}
```

This compiles. I tried the same in an impl:

```rust
struct FileFormat<R> {
    r: R,
}

impl<E, R: Readable<E>> FileFormat<R> {
    fn f(&mut self) -> Result<u8, E> {
        self.r.read_u8()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=15bdbd4d7445a3a5d067ef4e4665e237)

This fails with:

```
14 | impl<E, R: Readable<E>> FileFormat<R> {
   |      ^ unconstrained type parameter
```

The compiler suggests `rustc --explain E0207` but I'm afraid I haven't been able to understand the answer contained within if it's there.

Why does the former compile while the latter doesn't? Why is `E` in this case is unconstrained? How to resolve this so that the implementation will be able to take any `Readable`?

Comment: [The duplicates applied to `Readable`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=71c616ca7b2edb7ee5e590030b540878)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's imagine for a moment that *it did compile*. Here's a commented example which shows it would allow us to write broken code which would be impossible for the compiler to type check:

```rust
trait Readable<E> {
    fn read_u8(&mut self) -> Result<u8, E>;
    fn read_u16be(&mut self) -> Result<u16, E>;
}

fn f<E, R: Readable<E>>(r: &mut R) -> Result<u8, E> {
    r.read_u8()
}

struct SomeError;
struct SomeOtherError;
struct SomeReadable;

impl Readable<SomeError> for SomeReadable {
    fn read_u8(&mut self) -> Result<u8, SomeError> {
        todo!()
    }
    fn read_u16be(&mut self) -> Result<u16, SomeError> {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl Readable<SomeOtherError> for SomeReadable {
    fn read_u8(&mut self) -> Result<u8, SomeOtherError> {
        todo!()
    }
    fn read_u16be(&mut self) -> Result<u16, SomeOtherError> {
        todo!()
    }
}

struct FileFormat<R> {
    r: R,
}

// let's pretend that this does compile
impl<E, R: Readable<E>> FileFormat<R> {
    fn f(&mut self) -> Result<u8, E> {
        self.r.read_u8()
    }
}

// it will now allow us to write this code
// which is impossible to type check so
// it's obviously broken
fn example(mut fr: FileFormat<SomeReadable>) -> Result<u8, ???> {
    // um, does this return Result<u8, SomeError>
    // or does it return Result<u8, SomeOtherError>???
    // it's impossible to know!
    fr.f()
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4692418ddeff66aaee2d34143169f1c3)

The error type needs to be present somewhere within the `FileFormat` type. The fix is as simple as adding a `PhantomData` member to `FileFormat` so you can "pin down" a specific error type:

```rust
use core::marker::PhantomData;
trait Readable<E> {
    fn read_u8(&mut self) -> Result<u8, E>;
    fn read_u16be(&mut self) -> Result<u16, E>;
}

fn f<E, R: Readable<E>>(r: &mut R) -> Result<u8, E> {
    r.read_u8()
}

struct SomeError;
struct SomeOtherError;
struct SomeReadable;

impl Readable<SomeError> for SomeReadable {
    fn read_u8(&mut self) -> Result<u8, SomeError> {
        todo!()
    }
    fn read_u16be(&mut self) -> Result<u16, SomeError> {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl Readable<SomeOtherError> for SomeReadable {
    fn read_u8(&mut self) -> Result<u8, SomeOtherError> {
        todo!()
    }
    fn read_u16be(&mut self) -> Result<u16, SomeOtherError> {
        todo!()
    }
}

struct FileFormat<R, E> {
    r: R,
    e: PhantomData<E>,
}

// now compiles!
impl<E, R: Readable<E>> FileFormat<R, E> {
    fn f(&mut self) -> Result<u8, E> {
        self.r.read_u8()
    }
}

// now works!
fn example(mut fr: FileFormat<SomeReadable, SomeError>) -> Result<u8, SomeError> {
    fr.f()
}

// now also works!
fn other_example(mut fr: FileFormat<SomeReadable, SomeOtherError>) -> Result<u8, SomeOtherError> {
    fr.f()
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=771bff4265d4f37e5f3e9caca78a1e4e)

The standalone generic function works because we specific the Error type when we call the function:

```rust
trait Readable<E> {
    fn read_u8(&mut self) -> Result<u8, E>;
    fn read_u16be(&mut self) -> Result<u16, E>;
}

struct SomeError;
struct SomeOtherError;
struct SomeReadable;

impl Readable<SomeError> for SomeReadable {
    fn read_u8(&mut self) -> Result<u8, SomeError> {
        todo!()
    }
    fn read_u16be(&mut self) -> Result<u16, SomeError> {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl Readable<SomeOtherError> for SomeReadable {
    fn read_u8(&mut self) -> Result<u8, SomeOtherError> {
        todo!()
    }
    fn read_u16be(&mut self) -> Result<u16, SomeOtherError> {
        todo!()
    }
}

fn f<E, R: Readable<E>>(r: &mut R) -> Result<u8, E> {
    r.read_u8()
}

fn example() {
    let mut readable: SomeReadable = SomeReadable;
    // error type clarified to be SomeError here
    f::<SomeError, _>(&mut readable);

    let mut readable: SomeReadable = SomeReadable;
    // error type clarified to be SomeOtherError here
    f::<SomeOtherError, _>(&mut readable);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1023d269c95320e41fd1a706b809b10b)

It really all just comes down to making your types visible to the compiler.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. I ended down another path once I realized a separate `E` type made no sense because `SomeReadable` shouldn't have different error types. I settled on an associated type in `Readable`, which allowed `FileFormat` to remain unchanged. Your example guided the way.